# java : get values from table and apply formula

Tags: java

in the bellow code, I try to calcul the formula:

y=val1+val2+val4/all values

val is a string get from a table.

my aim is , for a row 0, get all values from each column "values" then calcul the formule.

after that do the same for each row.
but my code doesn't print me the expected behaviour for the first step.

thanks,

```
>     String[] values = { x1,x2,x3,x4};
>         
>         String val = null ;
>         for (int i = 0; i < values .length; i++)
>         {
>            val = table.getValue(0, table.getColumnValue(x[i]));
>             
>         }
> 
> //my fomula y = value[x[0]]+value[x[1]]+value[x[3]]/values[0..3]
> 
> int Num =  Integer.parseInt(value[x[0]])+Integer.parseInt(value[x[1]])+Integer.parseInt(value[x[3]]); 
> int Denum =  Integer.parseInt(val );
> 
> y=Num/Denum ;
```

Comment: (value[x[0]]+value[x[1]]+value[x[3]])  might be the problem. The concatenation may be facing error. You can try like 


int Num=Integer.parseInt(values[x[0]])+Integer.parseInt(values[x[1]])+Integer.parseInt(values[x[2]]);


@mention: i dont know if its a mistake, u have used 'value' instead of 'values'

Comment: @Mr.K : it was just a mistake, I used parseInt each time and now I got the sum, but how can I do it on Denim value, as it is calculated int the for(), I need the get make the same of all values of val ?

Comment: This is coz, each time loop works you are saving 'value' to val. So at last iteration 'val' will contain the last value retrieved only. Can you explain the part of Denum?..'all values' means ?
 If you want to do a division with each value on sum of values, i wu d say your loop closing '}' is wrong. Close it after calculation of 'y'. may be you can use y[] as array, to store each iteration step result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure that variable `value` shouldn't be `values` in this code?

Comment: no thsi what I said, Num value return me the concatenation and not the sum

Comment: have you tried doing `int Num = Integer.parseInt(values[x[0]]) + Integer.parseInt(values[x[1]]) + Integer.parseInt(values[x[3]]);`? @Mr.K sorry for duplicating your answer, I haven't seen it earlier

Comment: @lola, one more thing - your `for` loop is equal to simply writing `val = table.getValue(0, table.getColumnValue(x[values.length - 1]));`, maybe the mistake is here?

Comment: @ maialithar , I want just to make the sum of all values of val then make Num/Denum , but after the for boucle the val is equal to the latest value

Comment: @lola, it is equal, because you don't add new values, you just replace them. if you want to add them, use `+=` instead of `=` and make sure you're adding `int` values

Comment: I think you should change the first argument in `table.getValue` from 0 to row number viariable.

Answer (score 0):

```
"1" + "2" = "12" //string
1 + 2 = 3 //int
```

You cannot add String, have to convert them to number first:

```
int[] valuesInt = new int[values.length];
for (int i = 0; i < values .length; i++) {
    valuesInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(values[i]);
}
```

Then add the numbers:

```
int Num =  valuesInt[0]+valuesInt[1]+valuesInt[3];
int Denum =  valuesInt[0]+valuesInt[1]+valuesInt[2]+valuesInt[3];
```

Calcaulate Denum in the loop:

```
int Denum = 0; 
for (int i = 0; i < values .length; i++) {
    Denum += Integer.parseInt(values[i]);
}
```

Comment: Why do are you using for rwice ? denum is used twice here ?

Comment: to sum up: 1) get values (valueInt) 2) calcul of num the denum inside another for boucle ? if it is ok, how do I calcul Y ? inside boucle?

Comment: two different ways to get Denum(in the loop OR after the loop), you need to use either one of them only.